# Utilizing the "say" command in terminal

Tags: macos, terminal

Is there any way to make terminal execute the "say" command when I login to my laptop? I want it to have a greeting when I log in. Is that possible at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, paste the following into a file called `greet` in your HOME directory:

```
#!/bin/bash
say "Hello"
```

Then start the Terminal, and type

```
chmod +x greet
```

to make it executable.

Then go to the Apple menu at top-left of the screen, and click `System Preferences->Users & Groups`, then select your username, and on the right click `Login Items`. Click the little `+` sign and add the file called `greet` from your HOME directory.

Comment: what kind of file should greet be?

Comment: A pure text file, no RTF, no MS-Word, no extension.

Comment: is there anything I need to change about that first line? Is that supposed to be relative to the HOME directory?

Comment: You don't really need a program. Copy the text from the StackOverflow website by selecting it and pressing `Cmd-C`. Then click in Terminal, type `cat > greet` and press Enter/Return. Then press `Cmd-V` to paste the script. Then press `Enter/Return` and `Ctrl-D`, maybe twice, till it gives you back your prompt. Then do the `chmod +x greet` from my answer.

Comment: You can test it runs by typing `./greet` in the Terminal and hitting Enter/Return - check the volume is not muted.